# Как переключить проект на свой форк в intelij idea?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, github

Суть в том, что забыл форкнуть проект и склонировал оригинальный репозиторий, теперь по понятным причинам при попытка запушить проект мне выбивает "отказано в доступе", ведь это не мой репозиторий:

```
remote: Permission to TwitchRecover/TwitchRecover.git denied to NosferatuZoddd.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/TwitchRecover/TwitchRecover.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Вопрос в том как мне теперь указатель idea на мой форк?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное - нужно добавить свой репозиторий как `remote` и потом его указывать в push.

Для удобства назовите его `origin`. Для этого сначала переименуйте (или удалите) `remote`, с которого вы изначально склонировали:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
```

А потом добавьте свой:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/your_user/your_repo.git
```